How to add keys to Configuration which has multiple paths and Bind to Options
I need to add keys into Configuration for multi-tenants azure function while the function is executing.
For example :
Key 1 => "api:BaseUrl:tenantId1", "www.tenant1.com"
Key 2 => "api:BaseUrl:tenantId2", "www.tenant2.com"
Key 3 => "api:BaseUrl:tenantId3", "www.tenant3.com"

When I try to add the first key for example then it adds 3 keys ... it adds
Key                      Value
"api"                    null
"api:BaseUrl"            null 
"api:BaseUrl:tenantId1"  "www.tenant1.com"


and when I try to bind then it returns null
ApiOptions apiOptions = new ApiOptions();
configuration.Bind(apiOptions);

then apiOptions is null.
And when I try:
configuration.GetSection(nameof(ApiOptions)).Get<ApiOptions>();

It throws exception:
"Cannot create instance of type 'System.String' because it has multiple public 
parameterized constructors."

Here is ApiOptions class
    public class ApiOptions
    {
        public string BaseUrl { get; set; }
        public string IntegrationUrl{ get; set; }
    }

Here is a dictionary contains keys and values which I need to add later to Configuration:
var inMemorySettings = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"ApiOptions:BaseUrl:1ce1f5cc-7e01-4ee8-8e80-36e3e68405f3", "https://tenant1.lab.com"},
    {"ApiOptions:IntegrationUrl:1ce1f5cc-7e01-4ee8-8e80-36e3e68405f3", "api/id"},
};

Creating Configuration with keyvalue pairs
var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
configurationBuilder.AddInMemoryCollection(inMemorySettings);
var configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();
configuration.Bind(apiOptions);

apiOptions is null
Here the line which throws exception:
ApiOptions? apiOptions1 = configuration.GetSection(nameof(ApiOptions)).Get<ApiOptions>();

My understanding is that it throws because the key itself has colon ":" but I need to have the path and add tenant Id to the key path so that I can have multi-tenant keys.

Instead of being so abstract with your question, try giving actual code and config examples. What do you mean by "add keys into config"? What does ApiOptions look like? How does key 1 relates to "API:URL:tenantId1" and "www.tenant1.com". I'm quite confused by what you are asking.

Updated with more explanation.

I found out my mistake. I should use the TenantId as a prefix not as a suffix for the configuration key.
var inMemorySettings = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"1ce1f5cc-7e01-4ee8-8e80-36e3e68405f3:ApiOptions:BaseUrl", "https://tenant1.lab.com"},
    {"1ce1f5cc-7e01-4ee8-8e80-36e3e68405f3:ApiOptions:IntegrationUrl", "api/id"},
};

Then it binds fine:
ApiOptions? apiOptions1 = configuration.GetSection($"1ce1f5cc-7e01-4ee8-8e80-36e3e68405f3:{nameof(ApiOptions)}").Get<ApiOptions>();

